# OpenLayers WPS function fails in IE

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, gml, xml, wps

I am making a WPS call in OpenLayers which works successfully in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE9. The response from IE tells me

> Process failed during execution\nCould not convert  to target type
>   com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry

The same code returns intersecting polygons in both other browsers so I think it's down to how IE handles my GML/XML. Can anyone help out?

Code as follows:

```
function wpsExecute(featureA, featureB, identifier) {

    var polygonElement;
    if (BrowserInfo.browser == "Chrome") {
        polygonElement = "Polygon"
    } else {
        polygonElement = "gml:Polygon"
    }

    // set up the process specific parameters
    var options = {
        // set the wps process
        identifier : identifier,
        dataInputs : [ {
            identifier : "a",
            data : {
                complexData : {
                    attributes : {
                        mimeType : "text/xml",
                        subtype : "gml/3.1.1"
                    },
                    // get the gml:Polygon node from the xml DOM
                    value : featureA.getElementsByTagName(polygonElement)[0]
                }
            }
        }, {
            identifier : "b",
            data : {
                complexData : {
                    attributes : {
                        mimeType : "text/xml",
                        subtype : "gml/3.1.1"
                    },
                    // get the gml:Polygon node from the xml DOM
                    value : featureB.getElementsByTagName(polygonElement)[0]
                }
            }
        } ],
        responseForm : {}
    };

    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.WPSExecute();
    // console.log(format.write(options));

    try {

        OpenLayers.Request.POST({
            url : WPS_URL,
            data : format.write(options),
            async : false,
            success : parseExecute,
        });
```

WHERE `featureA` and `featureB` are as follows:

```
var gmlOptions = {
    featureType : "feature",
    featureNS : "http://example.com/feature"
};

// new gml 3 format
var gml3 = new OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3(gmlOptions);


compareFeatureGml = gml3.write(compareFeature);

var xmlFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
var featureB = xmlFormat.read(compareFeatureGml);
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may want to try http://www.stackoverflow.com as there are more coders there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with Format.XML. I had to redeclare a new XML format everytime I made a wps call.

```
var xmlFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
//read gml feature as xml
var xmlfeature = xmlFormat.read(gmlFeature);
```

Also, ie cannot use XMLSerializer...

```
    // this fails in IE
    var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var featureString = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(gmlFeature);
```